# Python pandas rank/sort based on another column that differs for each input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I would like to come up with the 4th column below based on the first three:

```
user    job  time  Rank
A   print   1559   2
A   print   1540   2
A   edit    1520   1
A   edit    1523   1
A   deliver 9717   3
B   edit    1717   2
B   edit    1716   2
B   edit    1715   2
B   deliver 1527   1
B   deliver 1524   1
```

The ranking in the 4th columns is independent for each user (1st column). For each user, I would like to rank the second column based on the value of the 3rd column. Eg. for user A, s/he has three jobs to be ranks. Because the time value of 'edit' is the smallest and edit the next and deliver the largest, the ranking for the three is edit - 1, print - 2 and deliver -3.

I know I should start with groupby the first column, but somehow cannot figure how to rank the 2nd column based on the 3rd that's different for each row.

Answer (score 5):

First, assign a new column which contains the minimum time for user-job pairs:

```
df['min_time'] = df.groupby(['user', 'job'])['time'].transform('min')
```

Then group by each user and rank them:

```
df.groupby('user')['min_time'].rank(method='dense').astype(int)
Out: 
0    2
1    2
2    1
3    1
4    3
5    2
6    2
7    2
8    1
9    1
Name: min_time, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can using

```
df1=df1.sort_values(['user','time'],ascending=[True,True])
df1['Rank']=df1.job!=df1.job.shift().fillna('edit')
df1.Rank=df1.groupby('user').Rank.cumsum()+1


  user      job  time  Rank
0    A    print  1559   2.0
1    A    print  1540   2.0
2    A     edit  1520   1.0
3    A     edit  1523   1.0
4    A  deliver  9717   3.0
5    B     edit  1717   2.0
6    B     edit  1716   2.0
7    B     edit  1715   2.0
8    B  deliver  1527   1.0
9    B  deliver  1524   1.0
```