# Ranking columns by a single integer

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, series, rank

Hi i am basically trying to rank a column in a dataframe into ranking position.

it looks something like this i am trying to create something like this. For person with same number of fruits sold to have the same ranking So that when i sort them by rankings it does not have any decimals. Can anyone advice me?

```
person | number of fruits sold | ranking
 A     |          5            |    2
 B     |          6            |    1
 C     |          2            |    4
 D     |          5            |    2
 E     |          3            |    3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python pandas rank/sort based on another column that differs for each input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45763829/python-pandas-rank-sort-based-on-another-column-that-differs-for-each-input)

Comment: @RahulAgarwal, I don't think that's a good dup target. There's no `GroupBy` involved here.

Comment: Related: [Pandas: convert categories to numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088652/pandas-convert-categories-to-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html). A few tricks here: take care to negate your series, specify `sort=True`, add 1 for your desired result.

```
df['ranking'] = pd.factorize(-df['number of fruits sold'], sort=True)[0] + 1
```

Result:

```
    person  number of fruits sold  ranking
0   A                           5        2
1   B                           6        1
2   C                           2        4
3   D                           5        2
4   E                           3        3
```

Comment: Hi i got the answer but can I get an explanation on how this pd.factorize works?

Comment: @cwerwf, The best explanation I can find is in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html): `Encode the object as an enumerated type or categorical variable. This method is useful for obtaining a numeric representation of an array when all that matters is identifying distinct values.`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html):

```
df['ranking'] = df['number of fruits sold'].rank(method='dense', ascending=False).astype(int)
print (df)
  person  number of fruits sold  ranking
0      A                      5        2
1      B                      6        1
2      C                      2        4
3      D                      5        2
4      E                      3        3
```

Comment: Can you comment on why `int` conversion is required? The docs say that ranks are 1 to *n*. So I believe `rank` should only ever output integers. For dense specifically, `rank always increases by 1 between groups`.

Comment: @jpp - Hmmm, no idea why output is float.